# cant get jquery draggable to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Ive been trying for a couple of hours now deleting code to try and root out the problem but the element isnt becoming draggable. whats the problem?

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="word">nǐ</div>



<script type="text/javascript">             
$(function() {                         
      $('.word').draggable();
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/8mn85bd8/. What errors are you getting in the console? Are you testing your code on a server, or locally by opening the file off your PC in a browser?

Comment: it says 7       jquery-ui.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: And as for the second part of my question?

Comment: doesnt work on local either

Comment: Well my question is are you getting the errors only when testing locally or are you actually testing on a server?

Comment: both :S so strange and annoying...